# Exponent of the cohomology of a product of groups

Tags: group-cohomology

Suppose $G$, $H$ are finite groups and $M$ is a module over $G\times H$.

**Question:** Is the exponent of $H^i(G\times H,M)$ a divisor of $lcm(|G|,|H|)$ for $i> 0$ ?

The Künneth formula answers the question affirmatively if $M$ is trivial or, more generally, if one of the groups acts trivially on $M$. But I don't know what to expect if $M$ is non-trivial.

Comment: Does this follow from the LHSSS of the (trivial) extension $H\to G\times H \to G$?

Comment: @Mark: What is LHSSS?

Comment: I think Mark means the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence. 

Comment: @Mark: I also thought about the spectral sequence  but since $E_\infty$ is just a subquotient of $H^i(G\times H,M)$,  I don't know if there could be extension problems leading to higher exponents ? 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any finite group $\Gamma$, if $I$ is the augmentation ideal of ${\mathbb Z}\Gamma$, then $H^1(\Gamma,I)\cong {\mathbb Z}/|\Gamma|{\mathbb Z}$, which gives a counterexample if you take $\Gamma = G\times H$ for any $G$ and $H$ whose orders are not coprime.